# SQL Server Pivot or UnPivot so confused

Tags: sql-server

I am working on creating a report using a SQL Server database. But unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Here is my database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable
(
    [ForYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ForMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TrainingDoneThisMonth] [bit] NULL,
    [FoodQualityStatus] [bit] NULL,
    [NoOfAllDrugTests] [int] NULL,
    [NoOfAllAlcoholTests] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO #myTable 
VALUES (2016, 1, 1, 0, 5, 10), (2016, 2, 0, 1, 15, 5),
       (2016, 3, 1, 0, 20, 15), (2016, 4, 0, 1, 5, 25),
       (2016, 5, 1, 0, 10, 30)
```

I need report in following format. Where column Names are converted into rows and corresponding values are also transformed.

[Report sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vt9c.png)

I have tried pivot and unpivot but I am not able to get desired results please help.

This is what I am trying:

```
select 1,2,3
from
(
  select NoOfAllAlcoholTests,ForMonth
  from #myTable
) d
pivot
(
  SUM(NoOfAllAlcoholTests)
  for forMonth in ([1],[2],[3])
) piv;
```

Comment: Add your try in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNPIVOT then PIVOT:

```
SELECT  Objective, 
        [January],
        [February],
        [March],
        [April],
        [May],
        CASE WHEN Objective IN ('NoOfAllDrugTests','NoOfAllAlcoholTests') THEN CAST([January]+[February]+[March]+[April]+[May] as nvarchar(10))
             ELSE CAST([January]+[February]+[March]+[April]+[May] as nvarchar(10)) +' True, ' +
             CAST(5 -( [January]+[February]+[March]+[April]+[May]) as nvarchar(10)) +' False'
              END as FinalTotal
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  DATENAME(month,DATEADD(month,[ForMonth]-1,'1970-01-01')) as d,
                CAST([TrainingDoneThisMonth] as int) as [TrainingDoneThisMonth],
                CAST([FoodQualityStatus] as int) as [FoodQualityStatus],
                [NoOfAllDrugTests],
                [NoOfAllAlcoholTests]
        FROM #myTable
        ) d
    UNPIVOT (
      [VALUES] FOR [Objective] in ([TrainingDoneThisMonth],[FoodQualityStatus],[NoOfAllDrugTests],[NoOfAllAlcoholTests])
    ) unpvt
) as p
PIVOT (
    SUM([VALUES]) FOR d IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
Objective               January February    March   April   May FinalTotal
FoodQualityStatus       0       1           0       1       0   2 True, 3 False
NoOfAllAlcoholTests     10      5           15      25      30  85
NoOfAllDrugTests        5       15          20      5       10  55
TrainingDoneThisMonth   1       0           1       0       1   3 True, 2 False
```

Comment: Working awesome... Thanks a lot. Can you please help me out with last total column?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hats Off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine unpivot and pivot to do this

```
;WITH data
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum(Cast([TrainingDoneThisMonth] AS INT))OVER() AS Training_True,
                Sum(Cast(FoodQualityStatus AS INT))OVER() AS FoodQuality_True,
                Count(1)OVER() AS Total_count,
                Sum([NoOfAllDrugTests])OVER() AS sum_NoOfAllDrug,
                Sum([NoOfAllAlcoholTests])OVER() AS sum_NoOfAllAlcohol
         FROM   #myTable),
     un_pivot
     AS (SELECT ForYear,
                Choose(ForMonth, 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr')        AS Month_name,
                data,
                name,
                Training_True = Cast(Training_True AS VARCHAR(20)),
                FoodQuality_True = Cast(FoodQuality_True AS VARCHAR(20)),
                Cast(Total_count - Training_True AS VARCHAR(20))    AS Training_false,
                Cast(Total_count - FoodQuality_True AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FoodQuality_false,
                sum_NoOfAllDrug,
                sum_NoOfAllAlcohol
         FROM   data
                CROSS apply (VALUES ([TrainingDoneThisMonth],'TrainingDoneThisMont'),
                                    (FoodQualityStatus,'FoodQualityStatus'),
                                    (NoOfAllDrugTests,'NoOfAllDrugTests'),
                                    (NoOfAllAlcoholTests,'NoOfAllAlcoholTests')) cs (data, name))
SELECT name,
       [Jan],
       [Feb],
       [Mar],
       [Apr],
       CASE name
         WHEN 'TrainingDoneThisMont' THEN Training_True + ' True, ' + Training_false+ ' False'
         WHEN 'FoodQualityStatus' THEN FoodQuality_True + ' True, '+ FoodQuality_false + ' False'
         WHEN 'NoOfAllDrugTests' THEN Cast(sum_NoOfAllDrug AS VARCHAR(20))
         WHEN 'NoOfAllAlcoholTests' THEN Cast(sum_NoOfAllAlcohol AS VARCHAR(20))
       END
FROM   un_pivot
       PIVOT ( Max(data)
             FOR Month_name IN ([Jan],
                                [Feb],
                                [Mar],
                                [Apr])) pv
```

Comment: Thanks Your answer is also working great. Sorry but I can accept only single answer.